# R's equivalent of numpy where

Tags: r, numpy

What's the R way of doing (in Python numpy)

```
np.where(b > 0, a, a+1)
```

for equal length numeric vectors `a` and `b`?

Comment: `ifelse(b > 0, a, a+1)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think:

```
ifelse(b > 0, a, a+1)
```

?