# R's equivalent of Python's np.select(conditions, choices)

Tags: python, r, numpy, equivalent

I'm trying to create a new column in an R dataframe based on a set of conditions that are mutually exclusive. There is a clever way to achieve this on python using np.select(conditions, choices), instead of np.where ([See this solved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109045/numpy-where-with-multiple-conditions)). I've been looking for an equivalent on R that allows me to avoid writing a gigantic nested ifelse (which is the [equivalent of np.where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51135233/rs-equivalent-of-numpy-where)) without any success.

The amount of conditions that I have can change and I'm implementing a function for this. Therefore, and equivalent could be really helpful. Is there any option to do this? I'm new in R and come from python.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give short reproducible example/use-case of `np.select`?

Comment: use `cut` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also `cut()`, *Convert Numeric to Factor*, with or without your own labels:

```r
df <- data.frame(a = 1:10)

df$b <- cut(df$a, 
            breaks = c(-Inf,3,7,Inf), 
            labels = c("lo", "med", "hi"))

df$c <- cut(df$a, 
            breaks = c(-Inf,3,7,Inf))

df
#>     a   b        c
#> 1   1  lo (-Inf,3]
#> 2   2  lo (-Inf,3]
#> 3   3  lo (-Inf,3]
#> 4   4 med    (3,7]
#> 5   5 med    (3,7]
#> 6   6 med    (3,7]
#> 7   7 med    (3,7]
#> 8   8  hi (7, Inf]
#> 9   9  hi (7, Inf]
#> 10 10  hi (7, Inf]
```

Comment: This is amazing! Even if it's not the exact equivalent to np.select(), it's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use `case_when` in R:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars%>%
  mutate(cyl2=case_when(cyl>7~"High",
                        cyl==6~"Medium",
                        TRUE~"Low"))

    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb   cyl2
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 Medium
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 Medium
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1    Low
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 Medium
5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2   High
```

Comment: What does `T` here mean? I guess it functions as the "else" or "default" condition, but why `T`?

Comment: that is equivalent to default in ```np.select```. ```T``` is short for ```TRUE``` in R.

Comment: I'd avoid using `T` for `TRUE`. It can create confusion, as we see here :)

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to pass the conditions and choices using a list? Similar to `cut()` (The solution proposed by @margusl below)